# C++ Conditional Templates Compilation based on data type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector

I was really hoping I could achieve this using C++ (11) Templates, but I'm facing some problem here. So we have a custom pointer object which internally could be of any of these types: a list of objects of its own type/an int/a char/bool/long/double/char* or any other primitive type, and it's decided by a flag that this object stores. There are global methods to get values of specific types from this object.

Now, my purpose is simple. I know that for my case, my object is a list of such objects, so I wanted to write a function like this as it's a common scenario:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> List_To_Vector(Object& list)
{
    std::vector<T> vec;
    int listSize = Func_Size(list);    
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i)
    {
        //let's say this function gives list items one by one
        Object arg = Func_Next(list);
        if (std::is_same<T, int>::value || std::is_same<T, unsigned int>::value)
            vec.push_back((T)Func_IntValue(arg));
        else if (std::is_same<T, float>::value || std::is_same<T, double>::value)
            vec.push_back((T)Func_DoubleValue(arg));
        else if (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value || std::is_same<T, char*>::value)
            vec.push_back((T)Func_StringValue(arg)); //Func_StringValue returns char*, so conversion to std::string should work
        else if (std::is_same<T, bool>::value)
            vec.push_back(Func_BoolValue(arg));
        else if (std::is_same<T, char>::value)
            vec.push_back(Func_CharValue(arg));

        vec.push_back(val);
    }

    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    Object listContainingStrings = GetListOfNames();
    Object listContainingNumbers = GetListOfNumbers();
    std::vector<string> vec1 = List_To_STD_Vector<string>(listContainingStrings);
    std::vector<int> vec2 = List_To_STD_Vector<int>(listContainingNumbers);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, C++ complains here as it tries to compile the code taking T = std::string, and int to string or float to string conversions would fail. What I really wanted here was a way to compile the int part of the code when the type is detected as int, and not of any other type. 
I can use Template function specialization or overloading, but then I think it really defeats the purpose of templates here and I could just write 8 different functions for 8 different types (e.g. List_To_String_Vector, List_To_Int_Vector and so on).

I also tried another hack, using reinterpret_cast<T*> on the address of the each return types, and then dereferencing it to add to the vector. That kind of worked, but has Compiler warnings and I think that's undefined behavior.

Is there a way to make this work properly?

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a really bad design. And if you want an object to handle multiple types, then why not use [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) from the upcoming C++17 standard? Or if you don't have it yet then [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/any.html)?

Comment: Why are your `Func_*Value`'s separate function instead of a single template or an overload set?

Comment: @Quentin : Because of Legacy code, and to perform Scheme programming language to C++ interoperability.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude:
Yes, really bad design. I'm just trying to sail through it.  :( . We are limited to C++ 11 (even that's very recent change)

Comment: Wow. So many nice answers! Please allow me some time to analyze each of them and mark one as answer, though I'm thankful to all of you!

Answer (score 4):

[The fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering):

> We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection.

`List_To_Vector` is doing too much – both conversion from `Object` to `T`, and filling a `vector`; abstract out the former and the solution becomes natural. First, `List_To_Vector`:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> List_To_Vector(Object& list) {
    std::vector<T> vec;
    for (int i = 0, listSize = Func_Size(list); i < listSize; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(Object_To<T>(Func_Next(list)));
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Now you can just overload or specialize `Object_To` as necessary. Here's one way, using SFINAE:

```
// not strictly necessary, but reduces noise a bit
template<bool B, typename T = void>
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;

template<typename T>
auto Object_To(Object arg)
 -> enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>{} || std::is_same<T, unsigned>{}, T>
{
    return (T)Func_IntValue(arg);
}

template<typename T>
auto Object_To(Object arg)
 -> enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, float>{} || std::is_same<T, double>{}, T>
{
    return (T)Func_DoubleValue(arg);
}

template<typename T>
auto Object_To(Object arg)
 -> enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, std::string>{} || std::is_same<T, char*>{}, T>
{
    return (T)Func_StringValue(arg);
}

template<typename T>
auto Object_To(Object arg) -> enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, bool>{}, T>
{
    return Func_BoolValue(arg);
}

template<typename T>
auto Object_To(Object arg) -> enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, char>{}, T>
{
    return Func_CharValue(arg);
}
```

Using something like [`boost::fusion::map<>`](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/map.html) can make this much cleaner if you can afford the dependency.

Comment: @PiyushSoni : If you post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can add an online demo to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's act one level below your `List_To_Vector` function. The issue I see is that you have a collection of unrelated `Func_*Value` functions, so let's gather them under a single, type-aware template once and for all:

```
template <class>
struct valueGetter;

template <> struct valueGetter<float>  { static constexpr auto &get = Func_DoubleValue; };
template <> struct valueGetter<double> { static constexpr auto &get = Func_DoubleValue; };
template <> struct valueGetter<int>    { static constexpr auto &get = Func_IntValue;    };
// etc.
```

Now `List_To_Vector` becomes trivial:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> List_To_Vector(Object& list)
{
    std::vector<T> vec;
    int listSize = Func_Size(list);    
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i)
        vec.push_back(valueGetter<T>::get(Func_Next(list)));

    return vec;
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c1d215a5e7c7ab3)

Answer (score 1):

Can I play too?

I propose a solution based on a template deleted convertion function

```
template <typename T>
T getTValue (T const &, Object const &) = delete;
```

and some not-template conversion functions, with the same signature, for calling the right `Func_X_Value()` function; something like

```
int getTValue (int const &, Object const &  obj)
 { return Func_IntValue(arg); }

unsigned int getTValue (unsigned int const &, Object const &  obj)
 { return Func_IntValue(arg); }

float getTValue (float const &, Object const &  obj)
 { return Func_DoubleValue(arg); }

double getTValue (double const &, Object const &  obj)
 { return Func_DoubleValue(arg); }

char * getTValue (char const * &, Object const &  obj)
 { return Func_StringValue(arg); }

std::string getTValue (std::string const &, Object const &  obj)
 { return Func_StringValue(arg); }

char getTValue (char const &, Object const &  obj)
 { return Func_CharValue(arg); }

bool getTValue (bool const &, Object const &  obj)
 { return Func_BoolValue(arg); }
```

The first argument is unused and is introduced only to select the right not-template functions, so the `for` cycle become

```
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i)
   vec.push_back(getTValue(T(), arg));
```

The template deleted function is introduced to avoid unwanted type conversions (by example: from `short int` to `int`) and impose an error, in compilation phase, if someone try to call `List_To_Vector()` with a wrong `T`.

So, by example, call

```
std::vector<int> vi = List_To_Vector<int>(listContainingNumbers);
```

should be OK but call

```
std::vector<long> vl = List_To_Vector<long>(listContainingNumbers);
```

because `getTValue<long>()` is deleted and there isn't a `getTValue(long const &, Object const &)` not-template function.

p.s.: cautions: code not tested.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a helper to deduce correct overload for conversion:

```
class convert
{
    const Object& from;
public:
    explicit convert(const Object& from): from(from) {}

    operator char()        const { return Func_CharValue(from); }
    operator bool()        const { return Func_BoolValue(from); }
    operator std::string() const { return Func_StringValue(from); }
    operator const char*() const { return Func_StringValue(from); }
    // ...
};

// ...

vec.push_back(convert(arg));
```

No need for templates.

This does have a drawback of having to repeat each concrete type even if they use the same conversion function. But you don't have terribly many of those. The overloads could be augmented with a template conversion operator that is disabled by default, but enabled for the types that reuse a common conversion function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using function specialisations to wrap each call, that way you can have precise control on whats happens for each type e.g.

```
template<typename T> T object_to(const Object& arg) { }

template<> int          object_to(const Object& arg) { return Func_IntValue(arg); }
template<> unsigned int object_to(const Object& arg) { return Func_IntValue(arg); }
template<> std::string  object_to(const Object& arg) { return Func_StringValue(arg); }
template<> float        object_to(const Object& arg) { return Func_DoubleValue(arg); }
template<> double       object_to(const Object& arg) { return Func_DoubleValue(arg); }
template<> bool         object_to(const Object& arg) { return Func_BoolValue(arg); }
template<> char         object_to(const Object& arg) { return Func_CharValue(arg); }
```

then give your Object class some standard algorithm methods and plug it into the following:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> to_vector(const object_list& obj_list) {
    std::vector<T> vec(obj_list.size());
    std::transform(obj_list.begin(),obj_list.end(),vec.begin(),[](const Object& obj) {
        return object_to<T>(obj);
    });
    return vec;
}
```