# c++ virtual templated function

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, virtual, type-erasure

Understandably, functions can not be both templated and virtual.
But there may be a super smart design pattern out there that would do.

My goal is to have a function which looks like as :

```
void configure(const Configuration &config){
     double stuff = config.get<double>("stuff");
     int thing = config.get<int>("thing");
     // rest of the code
}
```

Ideally, I could pass various configuration object, e.g. object that read from a file or from a database.

Here a (stripped to minimum) example of a concrete config class using yaml-cpp (I guess understandable even if you do not know yaml-cpp):

```
class YAML_config : public Configuration {
public:
  YAML_config(std::string file_path){
     this->node = YAML::LoadFile(file_path);
  }
  template<typename T> T get(std::string key){
     return this->node[key].as<T>();
  }
private:
  YAML::Node node;
```

Question is: what would be the suitable code for the class Configuration ?

Here some invalid code that shows the intend:

```
class Configuration {
    virtual template<typename T> T get(std::string key)=0;
}
```

If all this is just a bad start, any other approach I should look into ? I checked for "type erasure", but that did not seem to help (or did I miss something ?)

Comment: You could maybe have a protected non-template virtual function which returns a `boost::any`, then make the `get` template function non-virtual and perform the cast there?

Comment: Totally unrelated to the question.... But why are you passing in a shared_ptr?

Comment: @TartanLlama sounds promising ... any chance you'd elaborate :) ?

Comment: @rubenvb all the advantages of pointers without the disadvantages ...

Comment: @Vince And that sentence summarises all the wrong reasons to use shared_ptr. This function, as far as I can see, does not have ownership of the parameter. If the parameter outlives the function call, just pass it by (const) ref. All the advantages of C++ without overhead.

Comment: @rubenvb fair enough, I answered to fast. The real reason is that in my context I will need the config to be in the static memory and instantiated in a init function at runtime.

Comment: Still no reason not to use a reference (to a function-local static, in the case you describe).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134001/discussion-between-vince-and-rubenvb).

Comment: @Vince I think Quentin's answer is better than my suggestion. If you want to just go through a single function, you'd need to use runtime as a bridge, like this: https://godbolt.org/g/9ZkuDe

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a small-ish set of possible types, so I suggest a set of virtual functions grouped together with a non-virtual dispatching template:

```
template <class T>
struct tag { };

class Configuration {
public:
    template <class T>
    T get(std::string key) {
        return get_(tag<T>{}, std::move(key));
    }

protected:
    virtual int get_(tag<int>, std::string key) = 0;
    virtual double get_(tag<double>, std::string key) = 0;
    virtual std::string get_(tag<std::string>, std::string key) = 0;
};

class YAML_config : public Configuration {
    int get_(tag<int>, std::string key) override { /* ... */ }
    double get_(tag<double>, std::string key) override { /* ... */ }
    std::string get_(tag<std::string>, std::string key) override { /* ... */ }
};
```

Usage:

```
YAML_config cfg;
auto s = cfg.get<int>("hello");
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/378e306712363575)

---

But we lost the ability to declare `YAML_config::get` as a template -- types aside, the implementations are all the same, but we can't override a virtual function with a template.

So, now that we bridged the gap from templates to virtual functions to achieve polymorphism, let's bridge the gap from virtual functions back to templates to get our nice API back. This can be done by slotting in a CRTP between the `Configuration` and `YAML_config` classes: its role will be to generate the overriden functions.

Note: the `get_` virtual functions are now called `getBridge`. I have added a dash of macros to cut down on repetition. These can be further factored out with Boost.PP, for example.

```
class ConfigurationBase {

// ...

#define DECLARE_CONFIG_BRIDGE(T) \
    virtual T getBridge(tag<T>, std::string key) = 0;

    DECLARE_CONFIG_BRIDGE(int)
    DECLARE_CONFIG_BRIDGE(double)
    DECLARE_CONFIG_BRIDGE(std::string)

#undef DECLARE_CONFIG_BRIDGE
};

template <class Derived>
class Configuration : public ConfigurationBase {

    // Hide ConfigurationBase::get so we don't get
    // infinite recursion if we forget an implementation
    // in the derived class.
    template <class>
    void get(...) = delete;

#define OVERRIDE_CONFIG_BRIDGE(T) \
    T getBridge(tag<T>, std::string key) override { \
        return dThis()->template get<T>(std::move(key)); \
    }

    OVERRIDE_CONFIG_BRIDGE(int)
    OVERRIDE_CONFIG_BRIDGE(double)
    OVERRIDE_CONFIG_BRIDGE(std::string)

#undef OVERRIDE_CONFIG_BRIDGE

    Derived *dThis() {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }
};

class YAML_config : public Configuration<YAML_config> {
public:
    template <class T>
    T get(std::string) {
        return {};
    }
};
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf065e76c8586f34)

Comment: doesn't it remove all the advantages of using template ? In this case it becomes easier and more straightforward to forget about templates and create manually all the functions, virtuals and concretes.

Comment: @Vince the advantage of the template layer over plain virtual functions appears when you hook it up to other generic code. IOW, it is possible to call `cfg.get<T>("foo")` from another template parameterized on `T`. See [this recent answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806062/c-conditional-templates-compilation-based-on-data-type/41806521#41806521) for an example.

Comment: @Vince I've added another layer to the cake, so you can have your template again ;)

Comment: compilation of base classes work, but I did not manage to create the function of my dream, compilation gives error:  "invalid use of template-name ‘Configuration’ without an argument list" and "ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘config’ with no type" referring to the line "void configure(const Configuration &config)"

Comment: @Vince Use `ConfigurationBase`, you should not need to use `Configuration` from user code. Maybe you'll want to rename `ConfigurationBase` to `Configuration`, and `Configuration` to `ConfigurationBridge` so it's consistent with your existing code :)

Comment: I updated the function to take ref to an instance of ConfigurationBase, and now the compiler is complaining "ConfigurationBase has no member named 'get'". Anything I may be missing ?

Comment: @Vince did you take care to replace `// ...` with the fragment from the first snippet ?

Comment: I have to be honest, I do not understand anything. I am just trying to compile things first, and hope to manage to get soon my head around it. What is the fragment from the first snippet ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134019/discussion-between-quentin-and-vince).

Answer (score 1):

I have adapted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41846401/1563039) to a similar question from earlier today which uses type erasure and RTTI to get the effect of a virtual templated function. As I noted there, [Boost.TypeIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_typeindex.html) can be used if you cannot or do not want to use RTTI.

The basic implementation looks something like this (just fill in your YAML library stuff):

```
#include <functional>
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>

class config {
public:
    template <typename T>
    T get(char const* key) {
        T value = {};
        auto it = getters.find(type_index<T>());
        if (it != getters.end()) {
            it->second(&value, key);
        }
        return value;
    }

protected:
    template <typename T, typename Getter>
    void register_getter(Getter getter) {
        getters[type_index<T>()] = [getter](void* value, char const* key) {
            *static_cast<T*>(value) = getter(key);
        };
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    static std::type_index type_index() {
        return std::type_index(typeid(std::remove_cv_t<T>));
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::function<void (void*, char const*)>> getters;
};
```

Usage would look like this (note that you could use composition instead of inheritance if you don't actually need `config` to be a base class):

```
#include <iostream>

class yaml_config : public config {
public:
    yaml_config() {
        register_getter<int>([](char const* key) {
            return 42;
        });
        register_getter<float>([](char const* key) {
            return 3.14f;
        });
    }
};

int main() {
    yaml_config cfg;

    std::cout << cfg.get<int>("foo") << "\n";
    std::cout << cfg.get<float>("bar") << "\n";
    std::cout << cfg.get<short>("baz") << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
42
3.14
0
```

In this particular implementation, `T` must be default constructible; if this is unacceptable, you could use `std::any` instead of `void*`. In addition, a default value is returned in the case where an appropriate getter is not registered. You may want to throw an exception, or return a `std::optional<T>` or `std::pair<T, bool>`, to distinguish these cases from a default value actually being mapped to a specific key.

This solution has the advantage that sub-classes can register getters for any type. However, there are certainly more efficient solutions if you know the subset of types that `config::get<T>` needs to work with.